# Simple Quiz Game JavaScript

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm just learning now. Can you please help me, why am I not getting the correct output. This is my code:

```
//ask questions
var quiz = [
  ["When is Bulgaria established?", 681],
  ["What year was it before 16 years?", 2000],
  ["When does WWII ends?", 1945]
];

//variables
var answer = [];
var correct = [];
var wrong = [];
var correctAns = 0;
var wrongAns = 0;
var oList = "<ol>";

//function to print the result in ordered list
function printResult(result){
  for(var j = 0; j < result.length; j++){
    oList += "<li>" + result[i] + "</li>";
  }
  oList += "</ol>";
  return oList;
}

function print(message) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = message;
}



//looping, adding correct and wrong answeres
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  answer[i] = prompt(quiz[i][0]);
  if(parseInt(answer[i]) == quiz[i][1]){
    correct.push(quiz[i][0]);
    correctAns++;
  } else {
    wrong.push(quiz[i][0]);
    wrongAns++;
  }
}


//print logic
if(correct.length < 1 || correct == undefined){
  print("You did not guess any of the quiestions!");
} else if (correct.length >= 1){
  print("You have guessed " + correctAns + " questions.");
  print(printResult(correct));
  print("You have " + wrongAns + " wrong answeres.");
  if(wrongAns > 0){
    print(printResult(wrong));
  }
}
```

I have watched this code over and over again and I still can't understand why am I getting undefined as a result. In the debugger, after the loop I check my vars and everything seems ok.

Comment: what should happen ?

Comment: well, in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/owf1pgay/ it works. So please give a more specific info about what doesn't seem to work in your code :)

Comment: First error: Your definition of variable `quiz` is wrong (array of arrays instead of array of objects). Make it: `var quiz = [{"When was Bulgaria Established?":"681"},{...}...];`. After this fix, try and report if still not working.

Comment: How is this 'undefined' error manifesting itself? Is it in the console or printed to the page?

Comment: @levu in the same jsfiddle I get the same result: 1. undefined
2. undefined
Unordered list bullet?! undefined>

Comment: @FDavidov the asignment is to use two dimentional array.

Comment: @jedifans it is printed on the page

Comment: Actually, I missed that you are (wrongly) using a two dimensional array instead of an array of objects (question - answer). So... ignore my previous.

Comment: Yes @TsenkoAleksiev, I noticed that AFTER sending my post. I shouted out so high that didn't bother to keep reading the code.

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper it should print in ordered list the questions you have answered correct and print a message how many correct answers you have. The same for the wrong answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have three problems.

- reuse of `oList`, the variable should be inside declared and used only in `printResult`.
- Inside of `printResult`, use of `i` where `j` have been used and
- At `print`, you replace the actual content with new content.

Just a small hint with variable names for counting. It is good practise to start always with `i` instead of `j` and go on with the letters in the alphabet.

```js
var quiz = [["When is Bulgaria established?", 681], ["What year was it before 16 years?", 2000], ["When does WWII ends?", 1945]],
    answer = [],
    correct = [],
    wrong = [],
    correctAns = 0,
    wrongAns = 0;

//function to print the result in ordered list
function printResult(result) {
    var oList = "<ol>"; // !!! move variable inside of the function
    for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
        oList += "<li>" + result[j] + "</li>"; // !!! use j indstead if i
    }
    oList += "</ol>";
    return oList;
}

function print(message) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += message; // !!! append message
}

//looping, adding correct and wrong answeres
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    answer[i] = prompt(quiz[i][0]);
    if (parseInt(answer[i]) == quiz[i][1]) {
        correct.push(quiz[i][0]);
        correctAns++;
    } else {
        wrong.push(quiz[i][0]);
        wrongAns++;
    }
}

//print logic
if (correct.length < 1 || correct == undefined) {
    print("You did not guess any of the quiestions!");
} else if (correct.length >= 1) {
    print("You have guessed " + correctAns + " questions.");
    print(printResult(correct));
    print("You have " + wrongAns + " wrong answeres.");
    if (wrongAns > 0) {
        print(printResult(wrong));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Nina! :) Can you please explain me, why the oList is so important to be a local and if it's global it crashes. In this example isn't it the same? / it seem's it's not but I can't get why? /

Comment: you declare the variable global and initialize it with an open ol tag. then with calling `printResult`, you append the string with more characters and return at the end of the function the string. that works. but for the next call of `printResult` you have still the content of the last action inside and not only the starting ol tag. and while you do not need the variable outside (remember, you return the content), you better use a local variable for it and prevent that the content of the last action is inside.

Comment: Ahaaaaaa! Thank you so much, Nina! :)

Answer (score 3):

In your printResult function you are using var i instead of j,

Also you better use innerHtml+=message;

```js
//ask questions
var quiz = [
  ["When is Bulgaria established?", 681],
  ["What year was it before 16 years?", 2000],
  ["When does WWII ends?", 1945]
];

//variables
var answer = [];
var correct = [];
var wrong = [];
var correctAns = 0;
var wrongAns = 0;
   

//function to print the result in ordered list
function printResult(result){
//HERE:
 var oList = "<ol>";
  for(var j = 0; j < result.length; j++){
    oList += "<li>" + result[j] + "</li>";
  }
  oList += "</ol>";
  return oList;
}

function print(message) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += message;
}



//looping, adding correct and wrong answeres
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  answer[i] = prompt(quiz[i][0]);
  if(parseInt(answer[i]) == quiz[i][1]){
    correct.push(quiz[i][0]);
    correctAns++;
  } else {
    wrong.push(quiz[i][0]);
    wrongAns++;
  }
}


//print logic
if(correct.length < 1 || correct == undefined){
  print("You did not guess any of the quiestions!");
} else if (correct.length >= 1){
  print("You have guessed " + correctAns + " questions.");
  print(printResult(correct));
  print("You have " + wrongAns + " wrong answeres.");
  if(wrongAns > 0){
    print(printResult(wrong));
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me, why am I getting an Unordered list bullet for the wrong answers and not a numbered list? I can't seem to get that and I assume it will be the same stupid mistake as i - j.

Comment: Your var oList = "<ol>", put it inside the function, see edit.

Comment: I love you! Just changed that and everything works just great as it should!!!! Thank you! Why the heck is this so important, I mean if it is a global var it crashes?

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case if it was global or not, but you are initializing it with "ol" outside of the function and when you are in the function for the second time it does not start with "ol" so the final html is missing opening tag.

Answer (score 2):

Your main mistake is using i intead of j:

```
for(var j = 0; j < result.length; j++){
   oList += "<li>" + result[j] + "</li>";// here was i before
}
```

Comment: HAHAHAH, newbie here! :@